# Brakes shimmy on a hill

Tags: brakes, vibration, grand-caravan

Going down some steeper hills my brakes don’t feel right.   They feel choppy like they’re heated up and aren’t smooth.

Answer (score 2):

A shimmy or judder when you apply the brakes can occur from one or more of several faults: an out-of-round brake disk, a heat-spotted brake disk, worn suspension bushings, and (less likely) wheel or tire issues.

Brakes are important, and whatever's wrong is not going to improve on its own. You should have the car looked at by a competent mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

If the same happens when you brake on level surface, it is likely a problem with brake rotors, steering or suspension. If it only happens when going down a steep and long hill, it is likely you are overheating your brakes.

While all of the above indicate a problem, the latter can often be mitigated by using engine power to help slow down the vehicle (e.g. downshifting).